# How to find Scholarly opinions on Individual Hadeeths?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, doubts

Assalamu Alaikum.

Books? , free pdfs? , sites?, What to search on Google? It would be better if someone also included what are those 'Scholarly opinions on Hadeeths' called. It would be really helpful.

Barakallahu Feekum

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: This needs clarification. Scholarly opinions is scholarly opinion it might be a single view, a madhhab view etc. and have different meanings. You need to clarify what you are looking for hadith explanation or interpretation , or hadith authentication or whether a scholar considers a hadith as to be followed... As is this question lacks any focus and is too broad.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, It would be helpful if I got something like this, on the behalf of "Sahih al-Bukhari, Volume 1, Book 6, Number 301". Sheikh G.F. Haddad said, "
 " The problem here is the misconception about the.......... show ingratitude." and this website provides other explanations by Scholars, https://www.answering-christianity.com/karim/women_not_deficient_in_intelligence_and_religion.htm

Comment: https://muflihun.com/bukhari/11/582 this site claims an incredibly wierd Abu huraira's Hadeeth to be authentic, while other similar sites having the same does not provide its authenticity. https://muflihun.com/bukhari/58/188 this Hadeeth of monkey stoning is also claimed by the same site to be authentic. If possible it would also be rational to address the Muflihun website about these flaws they have, but for that I would need evidence, and for evidence I would need to rely on scholarly explanations. How to access those explainations? Hope I am clear. It could also be used to debunk critics.

Comment: Generally this looks like a case by case matter. However for any major hadith book among the 6 or 7 most popular (sunni) hadith compilations you will find a whole bunch of books addressing the content of the hadith etc. these would be your first address. See for example [Is there an equivalent to tafsir but for hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/is-there-an-equivalent-to-tafsir-but-for-hadith) and [this about commentaries beyond the 7 popular](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46014/are-there-commentaries-of-hadith-collections-outside-the-7-most-known-books)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for that, it's exactly what I wanted.